# ¿Cómo cambiar el src de una imagen con evento onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo este pop up pero lo que quiero es que al clickear una de las 6 fotos de la derecha se cambie por la imagen grande de la izquierda y a lo que sé es que puedo usar JavaScript.

```
<div class="img"><img src="img/auto1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="container-text">
            <div class="contenedor-img"><br>
                <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                 ...
                <img src="img/img6.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <style>
        .contenedor-img {
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
        .contenedor-img img {
           max-height: 150px;
           max-width : 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function $(element_id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(element_id);
        }
        function setSrc(element_id, src)
        {
            var element = $(element_id);
            element.src = src;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 5%">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/287" alt="" id="main-image">
    </div>

    <div class="container-text">
        <div class="contenedor-img"><br>
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" onclick="setSrc('main-image', this.src)">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" onclick="setSrc('main-image', this.src)">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Debes obtener de alguna forma el elemento a modificar cada vez que seleccionas una imagen. Puedes, por ejemplo, asignar una *id* a la imagen que va a ir cambiando. Una vez tienes el elemento, cambias su atributo `src` al ir clicando cada una de las imágenes de la lista, para lo que asignas el `src` de la imagen seleccionada al `src` del elemento (imagen principal).

Comment: Tu codigo me funciono perfectamente como queria pero al poner el codigo js en la pagina el estilo de mi menu y mi slider se eliminan o dejan de funcionar y solo cuando pongo tu codigo, porque pasa eso?

Comment: Cambia el JS por el siguiente y dime si aun pasa: `function setSrc(id, src)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.src = src;
        }`

Comment: Ya funciona bien todo gracias!

Comment: @EdgarGuzmán no te olvides de votar si la respuesta te fue de utilidad. Un saludo.