# Como cambiar una imagen por otra al dar Crick en un enlace

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera saber si  se puede hacer para poder hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo una imagen principal y abajo de ella tengo otras imágenes lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando yo le de Crick a una de las imágenes que tengo abajo me remplace la principal por la que yo seleccione, espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

aquí les dejo mi código HTML.

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="imagen-p">
        <img src="img/imagen1.png" class="img-princ" alt="Imagen Producto">
    </div>
    <div class="img-segundarias">
        <img src="img/imagen-1.png" alt="Imagen Producto 1">
        <img src="img/imagen2.png" alt="Imagen Producto 2">
        <img src="img/imagen33.png" alt="Imagen Producto 3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Siempre que hagas una pregunta, revisa si ya existe una pregunta similar ya hecha, y revisa si sus respuestas te responde como en el caso siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/330255/155688 espero que te sirva y lee sus comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lo que quieres hacer:

```JavaScript
window.onload=function(){
    let imgs=document.querySelectorAll(".img-secundarias img");
    for ( let img of imgs){
        img.addEventListener("click",function(){
           document.querySelector(".imagen-p img").setAttribute("src",this.getAttribute("src"));
         });
    }
}
```

### Explicación:

Lo que hice fué obtener todas las imagenes hijos del elemento con clase `img-secundarias` y a esas imagenes le asigné un evento, dentro de ese evento el cambio el attriuto `src` de la imagen principal por la segundaria y listo.

### Codigo completo:

> Para mejorar la precentación usé JavaScript para asignarle un tamaño diferente a las imagenes.

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imagen-p">
        <img/>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="img-secundarias">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVp9M.jpg"/>
        <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2fN4.jpg"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRjBJ.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            let imgs=document.querySelectorAll(".img-secundarias img");
            for ( let img of imgs){
                img.style.width="20%";
                img.style.height="20%";
                img.addEventListener("click",function(){
                    document.querySelector(".imagen-p img").setAttribute("src",this.getAttribute("src"));
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Imagenes:

Estas imagenes la saqué editando la imagen de tu pregunta:
[image: Telefono 1]
[image: Telefono 2]
[image: Telefono 3]

### Enlaces externo:

[Run in SoloLearn](https://code.sololearn.com/Ws8ETvQcFmKa/?ref=app)

Comment: amigo lo intente pero no hace nada

Comment: @LuisColmenares Actualizé el codigo, el anterior solo modificaba el atributo `src` de un div y no el de la imagen.

Comment: aun nada amigo no me cambia la imagen

Comment: @LuisColmenares No entiendo a mi me funciona, ver el ejemplo en solo learn.

Comment: ya me funciona amigo era que había cambiado el nombre de una clase y se me paso cambiarla en el JavaScript, Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Asocia el evento `click` al contenedor de las imágenes, comprueba que el elemento afectado (`event.target`) sea uno de los `<img>`, toma la ruta de la imagen que se almacena en el atributo `src` y asígnalo al mismo atributo del `<img>` principal. Intenta hacerlo y vuelves por aquí con el código de tu intento en caso de que no lo hayas logrado.